# Where to download Eclipse Indigo SR1 - 3.7.1?

Tags: eclipse, download

Where do I download download Eclipse IDE for Java and Report Developers Indigo SR1? This page:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

contains 3.7.2. This page:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Older_Versions_Of_Eclipse

links to 3.7.0. This page links to the platform/sdk:

http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.7.1-201109091335/index.php

But I need the Report Developers package with this feature list:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-and-report-developers/indigor

for 3.7.1.

Comment: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/eclipse3x.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/indigo/sr1

Answer (score 1):

You could try the bittorrent download:

http://torrent.eclipse.org:6969/